# "Logout" from Notes authentication

Tags: authentication, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a Lotus Notes application that uses the default Lotus Notes http login.

On our developer server, Notes has a html form that sends the login request to names.nsf

```
<form method="post" action="/names.nsf?Login" name="_DominoForm">
```

and the logout is done likewise, calling

```
/names.nsf?LogOut
```

This we found to be the case on other Notes servers as well - but then, this is the default, so what else to expect?

While the login is a form that Notes brings up automatically, the logout button has to be part of our web application (with backend in LotusScript), and I hardcoded the link to names.nsf.

Now a customer seems to use a heavily customized setup, where login and logout are not done using names.nsf. I don't know what they do for login - but when trying to call `/names.nsf?LogOut`, Access is denied.

Is there any way I can programmatically find out which action to use to log the user out? If not, the logout would have to be done in our backend (at least iNotes does it so). How can I program a notes http logout into a LotusScript Notes Agent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use names.nsf?logout. You can use any database. I would suggest using the one where you have the user working. If the security is set correctly on names.nsf, web users should not have access to it, so that is why you are getting the access denied message (and why you should not use that database for logout).

For example, I have a web application located in /websites/myApplication.nsf.
The logout link is

```
<a href="/websites/myApplication.nsf?logout&redirectto=/websites/myApplication.nsf/LogoutPage">Logout</a>
```

I am using a redirect to send the user to a specific location after logout. The page 'LogoutPage' is set to available for public users, so it is displayed after logout.